# Should one lose privileges due to downvoting questions or answers while reviewing them?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, downvotes, privileges

I recently gained the privilege to the review queues and for example, the 'First Posts' queue encourages one to downvote posts if they are of poor quality. But this conflicts with the wish (at least for me) to continue to be able to review post and help the site.

Is this immediate privilege loss on downvoting a post while reviewing it sensible?

Comment: You only lose rep when downvoting an answer, not when downvoting a question.

Comment: But the 'First Posts' queue also contains answers

Comment: @Ackdari This happened to me when I was reviewing 2k reviews for the first time, if you want to keep reviewing and are right on the boundary, don't downvote answers in the queue

Comment: @NickA yeah I realized that this is an option but is this something that a user should have to do?

Comment: It's a good corner case to be aware of, but you would expect to grow your rep to the point where you are out of the danger zone and then again forget about it for the time being.

Comment: Worth mentioning that if an answer that you downvoted gets deleted, the -1 gets returned to you. A typical day of reputation history for me  looks like this:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Qp43.png